# Getting Error while configuring ADB

Tags: android, adb

[image]

Trying to configure ADB so that I can debug it via wifi, I have checked on Google but not getting proper resolution.

Tell me what to enter in port address, device ip.

Moreover setprop service.adb.tcp.port command is running when i give space between set and prop, bit confuse...

Seeking for help

I got the following article, and wanted help in the same context.

- disconnect device from usb then tell it to listen on 4455
  adb tcpip 4455
  restarting in TCP mode port: 4455
- connect to the device using a specified ip:port. my device is using wifi
  adb connect 192.168.1.103:4455
  connected to 192.168.1.103:4455
- now do normal adb commands over tcp
  adb shell
- when your done, you can put it back in USB mode
  adb usb
  restarting in USB mode
  Help me

Comment: Check in your location of `C:/android-sdk-windows/tools` contain the `setprop` window batch file. I think its not available there. So that this error coming. Check it out and let me know.

Comment: yes setprop is not there!! what to do next

Comment: Simple, copy the `setprop` windows batch file from wherever its available and paste it to desired location of `C:/android-sdk-windows/tools`

Comment: +1 useful one for all of us..

Comment: setprop is not a windows command.  However, set is an unrelated one.

Answer (score 1):

These are commands for the shell of the android device, not for the host system.

Type adb shell to get the device's shell and then enter them.  If you get back to the windows shell prompt you are in the wrong place.

However those commands may not be effective on a secured device anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`setprop` is an Android command and is meant to be used in a terminal after `su` on the device (you can do `adb shell setprop ...` but when you `adb shell stop adbd` you'll loose your device connection). The easier way if already connected via USB is `adb tcpip 8600` and then `adb connect IP_OF_PHONE:8600` -- but this will only work if `adb shell` will get you a root prompt (starts with `#` and not `$`). Be aware that anyone on your wifi network can access your device!